# How to pick which column to unstack a dataframe on

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data set that looks like:

```
UniqueID CategoryType Value
   A         Cat1      apple
   A         Cat2      banana
   B         Cat1      orange
   C         Cat2      news
   D         Cat1      orange
   D         Cat2      blue
```

I'd like it to look like:

```
UniqueID Cat1 Cat2
   A     apple banana
   B     orange
   C           news
   D     orange blue
```

I've tried using unstack, but can't get the right index set or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bulk of the work is done with

```
df.set_index(['UniqueID', 'CategoryType']).Value.unstack(fill_value='')

CategoryType    Cat1    Cat2
UniqueID                    
A              apple  banana
B             orange        
C                       news
D             orange    blue
```

We can get the rest of the formatting with

```
df.set_index(['UniqueID', 'CategoryType']).Value.unstack(fill_value='') \
    .rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()

  UniqueID    Cat1    Cat2
0        A   apple  banana
1        B  orange        
2        C            news
3        D  orange    blue
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use pivot

Edit: With some more edit and inspiration from @piRsquared's answer,

```
df.pivot('UniqueID', 'CategoryType', 'Value').replace({None: ''}).rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()


    UniqueID    Cat1    Cat2
0   A           apple   banana
1   B           orange  
2   C                   news
3   D           orange  blue
```

Comment: @Wen, seems to be the same:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_table` with `fill_value`

```
df.pivot_table(index='UniqueID', columns='CategoryType', values='Value',
               aggfunc='sum', fill_value='')

CategoryType    Cat1    Cat2
UniqueID
A              apple  banana
B             orange
C                       news
D             orange    blue
```

Answer (score 1):

`pivot` works just fine:

```
df = df.pivot(index = "UniqueID", columns = "CategoryType", values = "Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take Me so long time to think outside the box :)

```
index = df.UniqueID.unique()
columns = df.CategoryType.unique()
df1= pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
df['match']=df.UniqueID.astype(str)+df.CategoryType
A=dict( zip( df.match, df.Value))
df1.apply(lambda x : (x.index+x.name)).applymap(A.get).replace({None:''})

Out[406]: 
     Cat1    Cat2
A   apple  banana
B  orange        
C            news
D  orange    blue
```