# How to keep certain columns when unstack multilevel pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
np.arange(2, 11).reshape(-1, 3),
index=list('ABC'),
columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    ['data1', 'data2','data3'],
    ['F', 'K',''],
    ['', '','']
], names=['meter', 'Sleeper',''])
).rename_axis('Index')
```

df

```
meter   data1   data2   data3
Sleeper  F       K      
 Index              
A         2      3        4
B         6      7        8
C        10      11       12

df.index.names
FrozenList(['Index'])
```

When I do unstack

```
df=df.unstack().reset_index()
```

I'm getting this

```
    meter  Sleeper  Index   0
0   data1   F       A       2
1   data1   F       B       5
2   data1   F       C       8
3   data2   K       A       3
4   data2   K       B       6
5   data2   K       C       9
6   data3           A       4
7   data3           B       7
8   data3           C      10
```

but I don't want to have `data3` column under the `meter`. I want to keep as it is as a column .
How can we achieve that ?

I tried

```
df.set_index(['meter','Sleeper']).Value(fill_value='').rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()
```

but I got

```
>KeyError: "None of ['meter', 'Sleeper'] are in the columns"
```

[How to pick which column to unstack a dataframe on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119915/how-to-pick-which-column-to-unstack-a-dataframe-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `unstack`, you can set `data3` as index by [`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `append=True` and then [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) on both 2 levels of column MultiIndex, as follows:

```
(df.set_index('data3', append=True)
   .stack([0, 1])
   .reset_index()
   .rename({'': '0'}, axis=1)
)
```

**Data Input:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
np.arange(2, 11).reshape(-1, 3),
index=list('ABC'),
columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
    ['data1', 'data2','data3'],
    ['F', 'K',''],
    ['', '','']
], names=['meter', 'Sleeper',''])
).rename_axis('Index')

df

meter   data1 data2 data3
Sleeper     F     K                             
Index                    
A           2     3     4
B           5     6     7
C           8     9    10
```

**Output**

```
  Index  data3  meter Sleeper    0
0     A      4  data1       F  2.0
1     A      4  data2       K  3.0
2     B      7  data1       F  5.0
3     B      7  data2       K  6.0
4     C     10  data1       F  8.0
5     C     10  data2       K  9.0
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!